# NSMutableArray to NSArray in objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert NSMutableArray to NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768937/how-do-i-convert-nsmutablearray-to-nsarray)

How can I Convert NSMutableArray to NSArray in Objective C.
i.e. without using loop that addObjects one by one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An NSMutableArray is an NSArray already (as it's a subclass of NSArray), but if you really need to create a new immutable instance you can do:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:myMutableArray];
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this code?

```
NSArray* array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:myMutableArray];
```