# Filtering NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm using Swift to create an iOS app, and I have a function that gets a list of all files in your documents directory and puts them in an NSMutableArray.

I'm searching on how to use a SearchBar to filter the items in a table view.

Is it possible to either put all items in an NSMutableArray into a regular array for me to use for this, or is it possible to modify the code below to work with an NSMutableArray

The tutorial:

```
  var data = ["San Francisco","New York","San Jose","Chicago","Los Angeles","Austin","Seattle"]
var filtered:[String] = []

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = data.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I didnt quite understand what you're asking for based on your code and what you're saying.

Comment: I'm trying to use a UISearchBar with an NSMutableArray. All the tutorials I find require a regular array.

Comment: I higly recommend you leaving the old stuff behind and start using the Swift arrays and dictionaries. var arr = [AnyObject]() == NSMutableArray()

Comment: var filtered can be let filtered, won't be a problem. If that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert your NSMutableArray to a normal NSArray, then there are a lot of sources on how to do this. On StackOverflow, there are a number of questions that ask the same, such as [this rather active question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768937/how-do-i-convert-nsmutablearray-to-nsarray). Swift-specific code can be found in [Apple's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithArray:). To summarize, you can initialize a new, non-mutable array from another array (e.g. an NSMutableArray) like this:

```
var nonMutableArray = mutableArray as AnyObject as [String]
```

[Source](http://dev.eltima.com/post/96538497489/convert-nsmutablearray-to-swift-array).

If you are looking for a resource on how to implement searching in a UITableView, check out a page like [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift).

Comment: I'm trying to filter using the solution you gave me, and while trying to use the index path in the table, I'm getting "[String] does not have a member named 'objectAtIndex'"

Comment: thats because a Swift array doesnt have that method, it uses subscriptions eg: arr[12] == oldArr.objectAtIndex(12)

Comment: Which part? Converting it to a non-mutable array, or implementing the searchbar? Typically, you will want to split 2 questions like this in seperate questions on StackOverflow to improve the number of answers you potentially get by having specific questions.